# A term for a set of vertices with a small set of neighbors

Tags: graphs, terminology

Given a graph $G(V,E)$ ans a subset $S\subseteq V$, define $N(S) = $ the set of neighbors of $S$.

Is there a standard term for a subset $S\subseteq V$ for which $|N(S)|\leq |S|$? Is there a standard term for $|N(S)|< |S|$?

I remember once seeing the name *expander* used for a subset $S$ for which $|N(S)|>|S|$, but I do not find the reference now. Then when $|N(S)|\leq |S|$, $S$ can be called a *non-expander*, and when $|N(S)|<|S|$, $S$ can be called a *contractor*. But these are all my inventions. What are the standard terms?

Comment: An expander is a graph in which every set of at most half the vertices expands in proportion to its size.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any standard terminology, although this condition appears in Hall's theorem.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot think of any standard terminology either.